# Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'ErrorModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I am facing following error while building an MVC core application.

> Severity  Code    Description Project Line    Suppression State   File
>   Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ErrorModel' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   JSViewer_Angular(Core)  86  Active  C:\Users\user\Desktop\JSViewer_Angular(Core)\obj\Debug\net462\Razor\Pages\Error.g.cshtml.cs

Any ideas behind this error.

Comment: Have you added a reference to it? Check your `web.config` / `'Packages.config` / the references section in the solution explorer

Answer (score 11):

Check your namespaces in your project. I got this when I renamed my root namespace and project file and I forgot one reference in the _ViewImports.cshtml file.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you have renamed project or moved around namespaces?
Check in Pages/_ViewImports.cshtml if @using and @namespace are correct

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have forgotten to add your model reference or directory to your assembly, or else there might be a problem with added references.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error now, I only publish working app and make some minor changes and this error about 'ErrorModel' is missong shows up..
I work it with custom ErrorModel.cs added simple as possible:

```
public class ErrorModel : PageModel
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public void OnGet([FromQuery]int code)
    {
        if (code > 0)
        {
            this.Code = "Status Code: " + code;
        }
    }
}
```

And change of @if (Model.ShowRequestId) of  on:

```
<h3>@Model.Code</h3>
```

Now its compiled without any errors.. But as I said.. don't know the cause of this error..